# How to properly deploy my flask app?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

My original app was like this (the routes previously aren't needed here):

```
    if __name__ == "__main__" :

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('dir', type=str, help='specify the images directory')
       .....
```

The python file itself is called `app.py` now to deploy my app on heroku i added a file `Procfile` file with the following sentence inside it: `web: gunicorn app:app`

and added the following to the previously shared lines of code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
#if __name__ == "__main__" :
def index():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', type=str, help='specify the images directory')
```

The error i get on the webpage itself is:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Debugging showed:

```
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041871+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-11 12:03:06 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-07-11T12:03:06.035624+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-07-11T12:03:06.035631+00:00 app[web.1]: if __name__ == "__main__" :
2018-07-11T12:03:06.035639+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041875+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041877+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041879+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041881+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041882+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041884+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041885+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041887+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041889+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041892+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041894+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041890+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041895+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041897+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041898+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041900+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 121
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041901+00:00 app[web.1]: if __name__ == "__main__" :
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041903+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-07-11T12:03:06.041910+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
2018-07-11T12:03:06.042123+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-11 12:03:06 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-07-11T12:03:06.201688+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-11 12:03:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-07-11T12:03:06.202039+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-07-11 12:03:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-07-11T12:03:06.328723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
```

The most important line there is `Reason: Worker failed to boot` which makes me think i'm not starting the app properly can someone guide me there(it's pointing at the line starting with if but it doesn't make sense to me since it's commented).

Even after deleting the line containing if completely and pushing i still get an error related to it.

Comment: where you run app.run?

Comment: what is app.run, you mean app.py?

Comment: you initialize the flask app (`app = Flask(__name__)`). now my question is where you added `app.run()` command to start flask app

Comment: Haven't actually the tutorial i was following didn't have that step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skc-ZEU9kO8

Answer (score 0):

Check if this boilerplate could help you.

```
import argparse
from flask import Flask


def create_app(config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.update(dict(DEBUG=True))
    app.config.update(config or {})

    # Definition of the routes. Put them into their own file. See also
    # Flask Blueprints: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/blueprints
    @app.route("/")
    def hello_world():
        return "Hello World"

    return app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', type=str, help='specify the images directory')
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", action="store", default="8000")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    port = int(args.port)
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```